# How can a user with only one rep offer a bounty of one hundred?

Tags: support, bounty

[This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/421381/do-i-need-a-comma-when-addressing-someone-in-writing) offers a bounty of 100 and the user has a grand total of one point. I'm sure there is an obvious reason and I am sure I shall kick myself when I am told.

But how does this work, exactly ?

Comment: To whatever curmudgeon is downvoting this harmless question: why? What’s the point? It’s asked and answered. Let it go.

Comment: +1 I wondered the same thing myself on a different question.  I solved the problem by looking up the user's profile, and then kicked myself.

Comment: @ab2 How did looking at the user's profile help solve the problem?

Comment: @Lawrence  I made a mistake in that comment.  After I posted it, I remembered that what I had done was read the rules about offering a bounty.  I just kicked myself again.  (But see Cerberus's answer, below.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reputation needed for the bounty has already been subtracted, so he had 101 before he placed the bounty. See his reputation history:

https://english.stackexchange.com/users/270619/user123456798?tab=reputation

He got 101 from his association bonus.

Comment: What a generous guy. Offering all of his association bonus.

Comment: So that he can make a 'clean start' from scratch on ELU, @Nigel J -- certainly a very generous person.